# How to access a users home directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that takes two different inputs. One is a file that has a user per line. For example, the file that I am currently testing with is:
peter
roger
casie
chloe
fender
The second input is the location where the output should be piped to. What we want to do with these two inputs is go to each user's home directory and look for 5 files (named a, b, c, d, e). We then want to count how many of these five files each user has. I know the correct numbers/output should be:
peter,3
roger,1
casie,2
chloe,5
fender,0
However, I am unsure how to get here because I have never done bash scripting before so I am out of my element here.

I have tried to use a for loop inside of a while loop (shown below)

```sh
while read line; do
        counter=0
        for i in a b c d e 
        do
 # /var/www/html/user_name/ is the home directory given to us in the problem
                if [-e/var/www/html/$line/$i];
                then
                        let counter = $counter + 1
                fi

        # would need to pipe $line,counter into $2 but not sure how 
        done
done
```

As I said above, I just need the output in the form of NAME,COUNT and I need that piped into whatever location the user inputs as the second parameter.

Comment: The current user's home directory is aliased as `~` in bash; would that solve your problem?

Comment: so could I just do ~$line to get the home directory?

Comment: You need a slash `~/$line`

Comment: Not sure what $line is meant to be here, but `~` expands to the full directory path without a trailing slash. So make sure to keep track of that.

Comment: $line would be the user's name because each line of the first input is a user

Comment: the ~/$line didn't seem to work, I am still getting the same error, it keeps saying that its missing

Answer (score 0):

First, I would build the directory path. Then use an `ls` with `egrep` and `wc` to get the count. Assuming your file is `test.txt` that might look something like

```
while read line; do
    printf "%s,%s\n" $line $(ls /var/www/html/$line | egrep "^[a|b|c|d|e]$" | wc -l)
done < test.txt
```

Comment: so this is a lot of syntax that I do not understand, what exactly is going on and would test.txt just be $2 since we want to pipe the output into whatever the second input is?

Comment: No. test.txt would be your input file. If you want to redirect the output of above (and $1 is your input); then `done < $1 > $2` **or** `done < $1 | tee $2` and watch as it runs.

Comment: Wow it works perfectly. But would you mind explaining what exactly is going on? I really want to actually learn the syntax of bash

Comment: Which part do you want more explanation of? The `$()` part, the `print` part, the loop part, or the redirection part?

Comment: Definitely the $() part, not really sure whats going on there

Comment: [What is $() in a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147424/52050)

Comment: ok and then just to clarify, does the egrep function count on its own or is that what the wc-1 does? I'm still a little confused on how it knows to count it if it exists or not (I've never seen the egrep function before and based on what I've read about it, it just seems like its a search function)

Comment: `man wc` "wc -- word, line, character, and byte count" - `egrep` is a command to apply a regular expression to lines from standard in, here `egrep` is used to match `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` or `e`. The lines from standard in are from `ls`, and `wc -l` (not `-1` it's a letter L) counts the number of lines that match the regular expression from the `egrep`.